# How to block access in a file using other characters together

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example.

I have this file in this link:

```
http://www.anothersite.com.br/example/product.view_bkp_20052020
```

And in my .htaccess file I have this rule:

```
<Files ~ "\.view$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

But, I can access the file when used characters together.

Comment: The `$` is used to match the end of the filename, whereas your file has `_bkp_20052020` after the `.view` value. Therefore the rule won't match the target URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @fubar. Also, after this change, can I have an impact on my application? For example, in controllers.

Comment: If you change this rule, it's possible that it could match and block access to other URLs in your app. You'd need to check. There are [tools](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) that allow you to check your htaccess against various URLs to see what rule(s) do or don't match.